# JS JSON Error 400, Value could not be converted to List

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm working on a college project and I'm at the finish line but I lack the knowledge to fix one bug and a few hours of googling hasn't brought me anywhere closer so this is my last resort.

I'm making a web-based quiz using **JS AJAX** and **C#** but the 'post' method always returns a **error 400**.

> The JSON value could not be converted to
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FrontEndGevorderdQuiz.Web.Models.QuizAntwoord].

I put all the answers the users inputs in an array `antwoorden[]` and want to post this to my `QuizController.cs` so it can calculate how much answers are correct and so it can give me back the correct percentage.

**My POST-Method**

```
fetch("/api/quiz",
            {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(antwoorden)
            })
            .then((antwoorden) => {
                return antwoorden.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                document.getElementById("extraDisplay").innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            })
```

**My QuizController Function**

```
        public QuizResultaat Post([FromBody] IEnumerable<QuizAntwoord> antwoorden)
        {
            int aantalJuisteAntwoorden = 0;

            foreach (QuizAntwoord antwoord in antwoorden)
            {
                QuizVraag vraag = _vragen
                    .FirstOrDefault(v => v.Id == antwoord.VraagId);

                if (vraag.JuisteAntwoordIndex == antwoord.GekozenAntwoordIndex)
                {
                    aantalJuisteAntwoorden++;
                }
            }
            float scorePercentage = ((float)aantalJuisteAntwoorden / (float)_vragen.Count) * 100;

            return new QuizResultaat()
            {
                Percentage = scorePercentage
            };
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you show a antwoorden object pls?

Comment: antwoorden array looks like this ["0", "0", "1", "3", "1", "2", "0", "3"].
the quiz is multiple choice with 4 different choices, each choice corresponds to a value from 0-3

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to see how you define  antwoorden  in the  javascript code

Comment: Do you mean this?
let antwoorden = [];

Comment: I see JSON.stringify(antwoorden). I would like to see  how you create this antwoorden.

Answer (score 0):

The error message 400 Bad Request mean :

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot
> or    will not process the request due to something that is perceived
> to be    a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid
> request    message framing, or deceptive request routing).
> [HTTP standards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)

and the message :

> The JSON value could not be converted to
> System.Collections.Generic.List ...

Indicate a problem with the model,
you can start to double check if the data that you are sending are same with the model in controller is waiting for ...

If you need more help, you can add your model and your javascript function that create `antwoorden`
Also here is a link that can help you : [AJAX Posts In Razor Pages And HTTP 400 Errors](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/336/ajax-posts-in-razor-pages-and-http-400-errors)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to spend some more time to figure it out and will reply if I'm still having troubles.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may in your `antwoorden`.

You can see my example.

```
public class Binder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The `antwoorden` in ajax example,you need to notice the `antwoorden format`:

```
var antwoorden=
                [
                    { id: 1,name:"A" },
                    { id: 2, name: "B"},
                    { id: 3, name: "C"}
                ]
            fetch("/Home/Test",
                {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(antwoorden)
                })
                .then((antwoorden) => {
                    return antwoorden.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    document.getElementById("extraDisplay").innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                })
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test([FromBody] IEnumerable<Binder> antwoorden)
    {
      //....
    }
```

Test Result:
[image]